# Angular2 access nested JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript, angular, ngfor

i´m new to Angular 2 in Typescript.I want to access D and G of my JSON with NgFor. Is there a way to access the elements?

```
[
  {
   "A":"B",
   "C":{
      "D": ["E","F"],
      "G": ["H"]
 } 
}
```

]

I also createt a Plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QXcPqDI8SljFumEYs5Xq?p=preview)

Comment: Is there a problem with simply... accessing them? it's just your avg every day object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngFor can't iterate over an object's keys out of the box. You must handle that yourself.

Pipes work well. Example: [Updated Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ahuTCHQ5aAkAHDix9iOu)

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any[] {
        let keys = Object.keys(value),
            data = [];

        keys.forEach(key => {
            data.push(value[key]);
        });

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you. You cant read anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: I find that the documentation on the angular https://angular.io to be fantastic. Aside from reading articles that's the go to source for me.